# Graphs with maximum degree three - 3-coloring

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

Is it possible to $3$-color a graph with maximum degree $3$ such that each color class is connected in polynomial time? If yes, is there some reference?

Comment: It is almost universal in graph theory that "3-color a graph" means "properly 3-color a graph", i.e., "color the vertices with three colors so that no two vertices of the same color are adjacent".  Is this what you mean, or do you mean "partition the vertex set into three sets, whose induced subgraphs are connected"?

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer:** Without the condition that "each color class is connected in polynomial time", the question is answered by Skulrattanakulchai in [their paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020019005003558) in 2006, which gives a linear time algorithm when this is possible. Note that by [Brooks' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) this is possible if and only if the graph is not $K_3$, and reading the proof on the wikipedia page it seems that replicating the constructive proof would be of polynomial time too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't say anything about the connectivity of the color classes, I think?

Comment: @MariyaKav ... My bad, I completely missed that part. Do you mind explaining what connected color class means? By definition, color classes are independent sets. Also, maybe I will keep the answer up until someone else answers the question fully, or I can delete if youw ant.

Comment: No problem, no need to delete the answer! By connected color class C, I mean that if we take any two vertices of C there is a path between them, where the vertices of the path are in C as well.

Comment: So if you take the subgraph induced by the vertices in C (i.e. include edges iff both endpoints are in C), then it's connected? But that literally contradicts the definition of 3-coloring a graph -  a coloring is assigning a color to each vertex such that the colors of endpoints of all edges are distinct! (Which is what I meant for color classes are independent sets). Do you mind giving an example of a graph? Probably better to put it in your original question too.

Comment: @MariyaKav As suggested by JBL, do you mean to *partition* the vertices into 3 sets, instead of coloring them? Coloring is a "reserved term" with special meaning in graph theory, in case you are not aware.

Comment: @MariyaKav Also, do you mind stating where this problem is from? Just want to remove the ambiguity that the problem is e.g. from an ongoing competition, as it happens quite frequently here.